# Stylize string for an email

Tags: javascript

How do I apply css styles in a string with javascript? I try the following way:

```
var text = '<b>stylized text</b>';
```

Note: When I send this string via e-mail, the whole string appears, as (`<b>stylized text</b>`), without the style applied. How do I make the text with the applied style appear in the received email?

Comment: *"When I send this string via e-mail,"* What does this have to do with JavaScript? Are you sending an email via JavaScript? How? Please elaborate.

Comment: How to send email? The problem should be you didn't allow html

Comment: Yes I am working on an email function sending the google app script.

Comment: Did you try to do like this? body:"<b>text</b> "

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this. Just use the HTML `style` attribute, so:

```html
<b style="font-size:24px;color:green">stylized text</b>
```

You can put most CSS styles in the `style` attribute. For more information, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp).

Note: some email applications support embedded HTML and some don't. From what I can tell from the results you describe in your question, yours does. But it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: the problem is that in the body of the html message in the email comes the complete non-stylized string?

Comment: and I'm working inside a javascript function to send email so I need the js

Comment: @JoãoAguiar In that case, please post a minimal example of the JS you're using, with a short string example, and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: "Please post a minimal example of the JS you're using." Where's the JS?

Comment: The above variable is enough to stylize.